# How to programmatically set <f:selectItems var> in UISelectItems instance

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I've successfully replaced `<s:selectItems>` (Seam) with `<f:selectItems>` (Faces) in all of my JSPs. But I also have some Java classes using the object model and there I seem to have one unsolved problem: `UISelectItems#setVar(String)` doesn't seem to exist.

**How can I fix my following code snippet?**

```
ValueExpression labelExpr = expFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, "#{item.findLabel()}", String.class);

UISelectItems selectItems = new UISelectItems();
selectItems.setVar("item"); // FIXME: missing method
selectItems.setValue(new ArrayList<Element>(elements));
selectItems.setValueExpression("itemLabel", labelExpr);
return selectItems;
```

The JSF tag `<f:selectItems value="#{items}" var="item" itemLabel="#{item.findLabel()}" />` works an supports `var`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an attribute appears to have no explicit getter/setter for it, then just put it directly in the attribute map as available by [`UIComponent#getAttributes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getAttributes()).

```
selectItems.getAttributes().put("var", "item");
```

Or, if it represents a value expression, then use [`UIComponent#setValueExpression()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#setValueExpression(java.lang.String,%20javax.el.ValueExpression)) instead (which is inapplicable for the `var` attribute, by the way).

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you'd like to migrate the view-specific code from Java (the model) to XHTML (the view) as well. There's in JSF2 **nothing** which is impossible in XHTML and only possible in Java. Declaring/defining/creating the view in XHTML is so much more maintenance-friendly than doing so in Java.

Comment: Thanks! We need Java classes which are generated by our dynamic form generator during runtime. Therefor we extend some UI classes and set them up them in our Java code. Doing the same with JSF snippets linked to beans proved to much pain for us.